# Website to add filter on top of photo

Tags: filter, web

This is a very beginner question, and I apologize if I sound stupid.

I want to make a website very similar to what facebook did for pride. Like this: https://www.facebook.com/celebratepride

I want to make my own transparency, and I don't want to use an image editing website, I want to have it all contained on my website.

Where do I begin? Is there some kind of engine that I can adapt and edit for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of image editing libraries out there. PHP's GD library will allow you to create images by combining elements. You will need to create a transparent PNG that you would combine with another image, as an example.

See this question and answer for more information
[Merge two PNG images with PHP GD library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366158/merge-two-png-images-with-php-gd-library)

Ideally we would need to know what your preferred coding language is and what your server capabilities are in order to help you more.

There are probably some out the box solutions out there too, but I'm going with what I know on this one