# PHP image manipulation wrapping image on of another image

Tags: php, gd

I'm working on a PHP project where the user can upload an image and preview that image on a product (Ex. mug, pillow). I have done almost all that is required to implement this except wrapping the uploaded image around the product image. I have done extensive search on that, but could not find any help. Could anyone show me the way please ?

At the moment I am using the GD library.

Best example for what I need is : http://www.zazzle.com/polyester_throw_pillow_16_x_16-189271445174968378

I am not sure how they are doing that.

**EDIT :** 
My area of interest is how they are blending the image according the product shape

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish the "wrapping the uploaded image around the product image"?

Comment: I have tried many image blending options in the PHP GD library. But I understand there is something more happening in the code to alter the shape of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's answered here: [Merge two PNG images with PHP GD library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366158/merge-two-png-images-with-php-gd-library)

Just make sure that the image uploaded by the client is smaller than your product image

Comment: Thank you for your response, but if you look at zazzle, it blends the image to according to the shape of the product.