# Loading Multiple small images into a single large image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a requirement to load multiple images into a one single image. These individual images needs to be clickable. I am looking for a solution in javascript / php or whatever that can be called from php as my main application is in php.

Thanks for your help

Regards
Latha

Comment: Posting some code and saying what you have tried will make it easier for people to help you

Comment: Hi Latha, welcome! SO is not a forum where you can drop a requirement and have other ppl write the code for you. We need your (trial) code to help you with your problem. Please provide a [reprex].

Comment: The question doesn't provide enough detail to suggest a solution.  Are these images different dimensions, size, and formats?  How should they be joined?  How many is "multiple" .... 2 or 1000?

Comment: Are you looking for a masonry layout?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a single image, use the [gd image library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to create a single image and use [an image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) to make the small images clickable. You will need to save the coordinate of smaller images to be able to create an image map.

Here is a question that will give a clue how to do that:

[Merge two PNG images with PHP GD library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9366158/387194)

In your case, you need to allocate a big image, where all smaller images will fit and put them into the right position. Then save the output image.

If you don't want a single image you can use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layout to make them look like a single image.